# Switch Logo Image Based on Slide

Tags: jquery, html, css

Working with Bootstrap. I would like to change the logo color or image in my navbar based on the slide. I was thinking I can designate which slide to show the dark logo and which slide to show the white logo. Is there a way to adjust the navbar based on slide through CSS or will I need JavaScript for this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Share some code Mike

Comment: if the logo format is .png or .jpg you can not change the color. but u can have several logo images and instead of changing the color change the url of the logo. as zan said plz share some code.

Answer (score 0):

How are you implementing your slides? You would need to provide code to answer properly.

But you could change the `src` property of the `img` element when the slide is chanched.

```js
var start = function() {
  var toarray = function(e){return [].slice.call(e)}
  var logo = document.querySelector("#logo");
  var slides = toarray(document.querySelectorAll(".slide"));
  var buttons = toarray(document.querySelectorAll("button"));
  var current = 0;
  var imgs = [
    "http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Vanamo_Logo.png",
    "http://demandware.edgesuite.net/aahb_prd/on/demandware.static/-/Sites/default/dw86f363db/Motorola_US/moto-logo-200px.png"
  ];
  
  var changeLogo = function() {
    logo.src = imgs[current];
  };
  
  buttons.forEach(function(e,i) {
    e.addEventListener("click", function() {
      current += (i == 0 ? -1 : 1);
      current = current >= slides.length ? slides.length - 1 : current;
      current = current < 0 ? 0 : current;
      var active = document.querySelector(".visible");
      var next = slides[current];
      active.classList.remove("visible");
      next.classList.add("visible");
      
      changeLogo();
    });
  });
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", start);
```

```css
.slide {
  display:none;
}
.slide.visible {
  display:block;
}

#logo {
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png" />
<div>
  <div class="slide visible">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
</div>
<button>&lt;</button>
<button>&gt;</button>
```